# Word for someone who says exactly what they are thinking

Tags: single-word-requests, meaning, word-choice, grammar

Is there a word for someone who would say exactly what they are thinking. Sort of if there is this boy named Bob, and whenever he has something on his mind he just says it out loud.

Comment: As Launius pointed out, we need a little more information.  There are various words for someone who says what they are thinking.  Forthright, straight forward, straight shooter, blunt, candid, frank, sincere, truthful... Please read the page on single word request.  "YOU MUST INCLUDE A SAMPLE SENTENCE.... [and] questions that show no research are likely to be closed."
https://english.stackexchange.com/tags/single-word-requests/info

Answer (score 1):

**Forthright** is a word which describes someone who says exactly what they are thinking.

> 'free in expressing one's true feelings and opinions'

[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/forthright)

> George Orwell's contention was that it is a sure sign of trouble when things can no longer be called by their right names and described in plain, **forthright** speech. . . . Christopher Lasch

[Quote](https://www.brainyquote.com/search_results?q=forthright)

Answer (score 1):

One adjective that might work is **unfiltered**, which *Merriam-Webster's Eleventh Collegiate Dictionary* (2003) defines as follows:

> **unfiltered** *adj* (ca 1775) **1 :** not filtered {*unfiltered* wine}; *also* : not modified, processed, or refined {*unfiltered* commercial publicity material —Paul Grimes} **2 :** lacking a filter {an *unfiltered* cigarette}

As the *Eleventh Collegiate* notes in its definition of *filter*, that word can refer to

> something that has the effect of a filter (as by holding back elements or modifying the appearance of something

A person who has no internal check on his or her thoughts and thus holds back nothing of what he or she is thinking may thus be described as *unfiltered*.

Answer (score 0):

Blunt might be a good choice.  My choice would probably depend on the connotation of said person’s behavior.  You are painting a picture for your audience; what do you want them to see?  Is the behavior inconsiderate?  Assertive or aggressive?  Or is it embarrassing?  Something else?  There are a lot of options.