# Is there a word for somone who constantly speaks their mind?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrases, expressions, idioms, metaphors

In this pandemic there are a lot of people who are speaking their mind without restraint. So, I was thinking about what phrase would describe that. I felt it had to do with like “open spout" or "faucet” but something of that ilk.

“There are those who are more measured and restrained, and then there are those _____ who only speak their mind.”

I believe the term conveys a negative connotation and is something in the neighborhood of an object that emits something, and is a popularly used idiom.

Comment: Duplicate offers << Forthright, straight forward, straight shooter, blunt, candid, frank, sincere, truthful...  >>. [a word to describe an independent man woman - believes in their thoughts and opinions](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/513135/a-word-to-describe-an-independent-man-woman-believes-in-their-thoughts-and-opin/513160#513160) has 'outspoken' (but closed as a duplicate)

Answer (score 1):

> Someone who is [**outspoken**](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/outspoken) gives their opinions about things openly and honestly, even if they are likely to shock or offend people.

- A few republicans have been outspoken in their support for the president.
- He was an outspoken critic of prescribing Chloroquin.

> - outspoken (adjective) direct and open in speech or expression : FRANK   from [MW](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/outspoken)

Comment: Thank you I really appreciate your help, but I think I was looking for more idiomatic expressions. I could think of firecracker, but I was looking for something more in the realm of someone who exhibits behavior that’s erratic and uncalled for. Like someone making a cryptic and uneducated comment about the pandemic, could be called someone who ______.

Comment: Would any of the words work in this thread under the accepted answer? https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/119199/word-for-someone-who-is-ignorant-and-proud

Answer (score 1):

How about [**unfiltered**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/unfiltered) (M-W): not modified, processed, or refined

Examples of ***unfiltered*** in a Sentence / Recent Examples on the Web:

*"That path is even more fraught for a president elected, in part, for
 his populist disdain for experts, a skepticism for multilateral projects, and a direct, unfiltered style of communication."*

— Rob Crilly, Washington Examiner, "Trump zigs and zags as he tries to balance coronavirus demands," 12 Mar. 2020